# Can an executable .jar file be called without having to use its full path?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I have a .jar file that I would like to be able to call without having to use a full file path to its location.

For example, if the .jar file is located at: /some/path/to/thearchive.jar

I'd like to be able to run it with:

```
java -jar thearchive.jar
```

instead of:

```
java -jar /some/path/to/thearchive.jar
```

when I'm elsewhere in the directory tree. In my specific case, I'm running a Mac with OS X 10.5.7 installed. Java version "1.5.0_16". I tried adding "/some/path/to" to PATH, JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH, but that didn't work.

So, how do I setup to run a .jar from the command line without having to use its full path?

UPDATE: Another item to deal with would be arguments. For example:

```
java -jar /some/path/to/thearchive.jar arg1 arg2
```

This can have an effect on the way the question is dealt with as mentioned in the answers below.

Comment: Note, the command:
    java -jar thearchive.jar
works fine if I'm in the directory with the .jar file (In the example: "/some/path/to".)

The goal is for my current working directory to be: /some/other/place/on/the/tree
and still just use:
    java -jar thearchive.jar
without having to use the fullpath. (i.e. java -jar /some/path/to/thearchive.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a variable to hold the directory:

```
export JARDIR=/some/path/to
java -jar $JARDIR/thearchive.jar
```

I'm not sure you can do it from environment variables implicitly.

Comment: @Brabster - good idea - you could also set the environment variable to "/some/path/to/thearchive.jar" and "java -jar $JAR"

Comment: This works a little better than the alias when you need to pass additional arguments to it. I'm using a full path to the .jar as followed up by @jabbie and calling with "java -jar $JAR" then passing the arguments. This is working as expected.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't.

Running a jar with `-jar` does not involve any kind of classpath mechanism since the jar file *is* the classpath.

Alternatively use a shell alias to launch the jar or a small script file.

Answer (score 3):

According [to Sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html):

```
java -jar app.jar
```

> To run the application from jar file that is in other directory, we need to specify the path of that directory as below: **`java -jar path/app.jar`**
>
> where path is the directory path at which this app.jar resides.

So either out the path in a "standard" environment variable or define a wrapper which would be in your PATH

Comment: as described in @Brabster's answer and @jabbie's follow up, I'm exporting the full path to the .jar file like:

    export THEJAR=/some/path/to/thearchive.jar

and running it via:

    java -jar $THEJAR 

This allows me to also send arguments as necessary, like:

    java -jar $THEJAR arg1 arg2

And everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. If you have the jar specified in your CLASSPATH you could just call java with the main class specified. (i.e java com.test.Main) Alternatively you could create an alias in you shell to execute the command

```
alias execJar="java -jar /some/path/to/thearchive.jar"
```

Or another alternative is to create a wrapper script to execute it.

Comment: This answer is helpful, but it runs into issues with passing additional arguments. As long as you don't need to pass additional arguments (which I didn't list in my initial question), this should work fine.

Comment: @stimulatingpixels You can pass additional arguments to an aliased command, or if you need them to be inserted at an arbitrary location create a function instead. A wrapper script can also be written to pass through the additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The Java system itself does not give you a way to specify something like JAR_PATH (a list of places to look for jar files).  The other answers given use the MAC/Unix shell capabilities:

1. Setting an environment variable
2. Setting an alias
3. Possibly using a symbolic link (to the file or to the directory).

What might be helpful is to find out why specifying the entire path is a problem.  That may guide us as to which answer is best or possibly find a completely different solution to your problem.

Comment: It is really just a matter of convenience. One of the specific example is Sun's Multi-Schema XML Validator (MSV) which I use to validate XML files against schemas via the command line. When I'm in a terminal at the directory where the .xml and .xsd files are located it's nicer to be able to do something like "java -jar $MSV schema.xsd doc.xml" than "java -jar /path/to/the/real/msv.jar schema.xsd doc.xml".

Comment: In that case using an environment variable or alias will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To run a .jar file without typing the full path you can put it in your classpath and run it by typing:

```
java fullclassname arg1 arg2
```

Mac OSX Developer Library [recommends](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1170/_index.html) 'additional jar files that need to be placed on the system classpath be placed in the `/Library/Java/Extensions` folder. You can also put them in your own `Library/Java/Extensions` folder, but you will probably have to create the `Java` and `Extensions` folders.

If you do not know the full name of the main class in your .jar file, you can expand it and look in the `MANIFEST.MF` file in the `META-INF` folder. The `Main-Class:` line will tell you.

So, for example, to run the [saxon9he.jar](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) put it in `/Library/Java/Extensions` and you can type (from whichever folder you want)

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform arg1 arg2...
```

Almost as short as typing `java -jar jarfile.jar arg1 arg2`, and you don't need to change any environment variables.

In short, if the jar is in your classpath, use the classname and you don't need the pathname.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no extra command line option for the location of jars or an environment variable is taken into account I am also not aware of an easy solution but would be highly interested in it as well.

A different approach could be to use a zsh wrapper script to get such a behaviour:

~/.scripts/java # .scripts at a prior position in your $PATH variable than java itself

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# get -jar option and remove from $@ (-D option)
zparseopts -D jar:=jarname 
if [ -e $JAR_PATH/$jarname[2] ];
then
    java -jar $JAR_PATH/$jarname[2] $@
elif [ -e $jarname[2] ];
then
    java -jar $jarname[2] $@
else
    java $@
fi
```

An advantage of `zparseopts` is that it can strip off the -jar option but all other options are retained within $@.

A further improvement would be to extend [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org) or zsh-completion for the java command option -jar. For instance bash-completion of `java -jar` restricts file listings to *.jar files. For convenient usage someone could extend this by not only looking into current path but into $JAR_PATH. As a starting point see following [unix.sx question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34238/complete-files-from-a-different-directory-in-bash).

But this solution doesn't look too good either.